# passing a returned value to another function, javascript

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, decorator

Given the following piece of code:

```
 function Foo() {};
 Foo.prototype.one = fluent(function(a , b) {
    return a + b;
 });
 Foo.prototype.two = fluent(function(c) {
    var d = c + 0.15; //0.15 cause I just couldnt thougth anything else at this moment...
    return d;
 });
```

ok that's all good for the moment, now let's say fluent is a decorator function that allows me to implement it like this:

```
var test = new Foo();
test.one(10, 5).two(); //here is the problem...
```

Thinking as it was a promise, how can I modify this code in order to make the returned valued of one available on two??? meaning, c should be the returned valued of one(), while keeping the sample implementation.

Here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/andresmijares/kq9wtejt/);

Comment: if you're chaining you need to use `return this;`

Comment: @Data if I use return this I have to change the class, that is not an option at this case.

Comment: why can't you change the class?

Comment: cause is not allowed, the sample is for illustraition, I'm aware that returning this will allow me to chain, however, this is not what I'm looking for, thanks anyway.

Comment: Should `console.log(test.one(10, 5))` print out `15` still?

Comment: Well a function can only return one thing, and it can't tell how or why it was invoked.

Comment: `var test = new Foo();`  `test.two(test.one(10, 5));`

Comment: I'm agree with this, but I'm looking for a way to maintain the implementation I'm proposing @pherris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution utilised the answer of [Dark Falcon](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32702802/1447675) and makes a little extent to the feature of returning a value or the chain.

Javascript offers the possibillity to request a primitive value of the object, [`Object.prototype.valueOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/valueOf)
 . In this case it may be used to get a value in case we need a value and on other cases, there is the object returned.

For more information have a look to this article [Object-to-Primitive Conversions in JavaScript](http://www.adequatelygood.com/Object-to-Primitive-Conversions-in-JavaScript.html).

Another addition is argument control at `fluent` and the call of the methods. If arguments are given, then the arguments are taken, if not given, then the `this.$lastreturn` is used.

```js
function fluent(impl) {
    return function () {
        var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
        // Prepend the last return value for this object only if arg length is 0
        if (!args.length && typeof this.$lastReturn !== 'undefined') {
            args.unshift(this.$lastReturn);
        }
        this.$lastReturn = impl.apply(this, args);
        return this;
    }
}
function Foo() { };
Foo.prototype.one = fluent(function (a, b) {
    return a + b;
});
Foo.prototype.two = fluent( function (c) {
    return c + 0.77;
});

// this returns the primitive value
Foo.prototype.valueOf = function (c) {
    return this.$lastReturn;
};

var test = new Foo();
var x = test.one(10, 5);
document.write(x + '<br>');        // 15
document.write(typeof x + '<br>'); // object
var y = x.two();
document.write(y + '<br>');        // 15.77
document.write(typeof y + '<br>'); // object
var z = y.two(35);
document.write(z + '<br>');        // 35.77
document.write(typeof z + '<br>'); // object
```

Answer (score 3):

I would propose the following definition of `fluent`. Note that if needed, the final return value is in `this.$lastReturn`:

```
function fluent(impl) {
  return function() {
    // Convert arguments to a real array
    var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);

    // Prepend the last return value for this object
    if(typeof this.$lastReturn != 'undefined')
      args.unshift(this.$lastReturn);

    // Invoke the function and save the return value
    this.$lastReturn = impl.apply(this, args);

    // Return this to allow chaining of the next fluent call
    return this;
  }
}
```

Comment: If the wrapped function always returns `this`, how do you ever get a final value?

Comment: @caasjj well the code here does correctly pick up the previous result and prepend it to the arguments passed to the next function.

Comment: almost! this is the best solution I have so far, however, if I do it with not chain. test.two(10); should return 1.5 but an object.

Comment: @andresmijares25: As noted in the comments above, "Well a function can only return one thing". You can't do both, period. It simply is not possible. You could selectively choose which functions to wrap, or you can just access the final return value via the special property.

Comment: @DarkFalcon, that is not right in all cases. please see my answer.